# Stack Overflow does not load under Chrome

Tags: support, google-chrome

I am trying to open Stack Overflow in Chrome but it is not opening. I can open it from four others laptops, but it is not opening in Chrome. What is the reason?

I am getting this error:

> **Oops! Google Chrome could not find stackoverflow.com**

It works in Mozilla.

Comment: Does stack overflow work in firefox? Do other pages work in chrome?

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Are you getting network/JavaScript errors in the console (F12)? Are things OK in other browsers? You really need to supply enough detail if you want us to even start helping.

Comment: it is not working for me in chrome but works in mozila

Comment: Clear your cache, close all instances of chrome and try again. It is very strange to get a network error like this that is affecting only one browser.

Comment: @Oded I try to open it from friends laptop but same error

Comment: Where are you accessing the Internet from? Work? School? Home?

Comment: Handy tool: http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/stackoverflow.com; not much we can do to help you, to be honest. Sorry!

Comment: From home.I daily open it.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your modem/router? Fact is, it is up for everyone else.

Comment: yes it restart it many time

Comment: @Emrakul There's a shorter one: http://isup.me

Comment: bad proxy settings?

Comment: no proxy is not a problem because i just open it yesterday

Comment: if proxy was a problem then it should be open from other pc

Comment: Hay I am also getting the same problem..

Comment: in IE it is also not opening

Comment: Same issue i am facing any solution?

Comment: I am from Pakistan.

Comment: If it works with another browser on the same computer, it's very unlikely that it's a hardware/network problem.

Comment: IPv4 or IPv6? See also http://test-ipv6.com/ (with all browsers).

Comment: i test it to all browsers

Comment: i should shutdown pc and then chek it 
let me c this again

Comment: If it's opening on another browser, it's not a network issue, and it's not a DNS issue either. It's either browser specific (clear cache, or reinstall Chrome), or (**very** unlikely) that SO is somehow filtering/dropping HTTP requests coming from Chrome user agents, coming from a specific region. It would be awesome to test this by connecting through a VPN and checking if it opens up.

Comment: Better yet, try this: install [this extension in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg), and use it to choose Firefox > Windows Firefox 15, then try opening up SO.

Comment: @Alaa - "(very unlikely) that SO is somehow filtering/dropping HTTP requests coming from Chrome user agents, coming from a specific region.!". No way we are doing that...

Comment: @Oded yes, that's why I have "very unlikely" in there. Also, I am **in no way** saying you're deliberately doing it, I'm saying that the packets might be getting dropped somehow...don't know how though; I never worked with web servers...maybe some kind of configuration, or a change that has been made that only affects Chrome browsers.

Comment: @Alaa - Knowing a bit about our infrastructure, I do have to say it appears to me to be a localized issue. Possibly filtering done on an ISP level (seeing as it isn't just one person reporting it).

Comment: Unselect "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" under Chrome's settings --> "Show Advanced Settings" or visit chrome://net-internals/ and hit "Clear Host Cache" Chrome uses it's own DNS prefetching by default which would explain why other browsers work and Chrome doesn't.

Answer (score 8):

From the sounds of it you're being blocked by Chrome's internal DNS prefetcher which overrides your computer/router's DNS settings unless you tell it not to.

If you unchecked "Predict network actions to improve page load performance" under Settings --> "Show Advanced Settings" in Chrome and restart it, it'll rely on your local DNS settings rather than Chrome's preset ones which should fix your issue, or at the very least make loading pages in Chrome the same as loading pages in Firefox.

Comment: I don't see that seeing in chromium

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes these things pop up. It might be due to some misconfigured firewall. If everything is okay, and you're pretty sure of it, clear your cookies, cache, history. Restart Chrome. It should work.

If it still DOES NOT work, there's a way out- 
Open Task Manager.
Close all Chrome.exe processes.
Restart your computer.
Start Chrome.

That's it. A quick-fix.

Comment: It looks like a DNS error, and looks broader than the local browser level. Also, it appears they've tried this.

Comment: If it's a DNS error it should be a temporary one. Otherwise use Google Open DNS ip- 8.8.8.8.

Answer (score 0):

There is something wrong with a browser setting, probably.

I have fixed this issue by:

1. resetting the browser settings (Settings-> Advance setting -> Reset settings)
2. cleaning the cache

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem. It solved for me by changing LAN settings in chrome to 'Use a proxy server for your LAN' and providing the address of our proxy server. But I wonder how it got reset

Answer (score 0):

Had issues with Stackoverflow and other sites for while. What fixed the issue for me was to deactivate all the Google extensions (docs, sheets, slides).

I had tried to reset my settings with no effect. Resetting the setting is supposed to deactivate all the extensions, but it didn't seem to work for the extensions above.